# Proteus oscilloscope errors

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, proteus, error

I have homework in Proteus, but because of the virus my teacher can't explain very well how to use this program.

I have a circuit and I can't play it. I attached the circuit and the errors that I get. Can someone help me make it work?

[image]

Comment: You havent attached the errors. You also have a node unconnected near the bootom of the transformer, and you've shorted the 2 oscilliscope probes together. By doing this, you've also shorted the AC power supply together too.

Comment: I have to use Proteus for legacy projects. You have my sympathies

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have circled where you have an unconnected node. This isn't going to do anything. Where I have drawn a (very crude) arrow, because of the way you've done your scope probes, the AC power supply is shorted together.

The unconnected node will likely just mean your simulation will run, but you won't get any reliable measurements. Shorting the power supply is going to cause an error and the simulation will not run.

Comment: i just post an answer with how my circuit should be.do you think it s ok after i ll do what you told me?

Comment: @george Please add that information to the question. Don't post it as an answer as it is not an answer. And no, it is not the same circuit. The oscilloscope in Proteus has a built in 0V reference. The 2 wires in your example going to the negative side of the power supply are the GND nodes. You do not need them. Also note that the example diagram is DC, you are using AC. You are also using the wrong type of transformer. You can;t just leave a floating node and expect it to work

Comment: @MGC it s the first time when i use this program and this platform too.do you have discord/skype/facebook or smh to ask you some questions about this exercice?thank you!

Comment: This site isn't like that. You ask questions here and have answers here. You simply need to remove the 2 connections from the oscilloscope to the negative side of the power, replace the power with a DC source and choose a transformer that matches the example